# Kubernetes autoscaler targetCPUUtilizationPercentage

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm defining this autoscaler with kubernetes and GCE and I'm wondering what exactly should I specify for `targetCPUUtilizationPercentage`. That target points to what exactly? Is it the total CPU in my cluster? When the pods referenced in this autoscaler consume more than `targetCPUUtilizationPercentage` what happens?

Comment: I think it is the targetCPUUtilizationPercentage of each node. This also includes the CPU of pods in that node

Comment: May be someone can comment if targetCPUUtilizationPercentage is set to 200? in case request = 100m, this means that autoscaling would start only after 200m cpu usage?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The CPU utilization is the average CPU usage of a all pods in a deployment across the last minute divided by the requested CPU of this deployment. If the mean of the pods' CPU utilization is higher than the target you defined, then your replicas will be adjusted accordingly.

You can read more about this topic [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/blob/main/content/en/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale.md#algorithm-details).

Comment: Resource unavailable. could you please update the link ?

Comment: Hi, If I have defined my resources.requests.cpu as 100m and  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage as 50% in hpa. Does it mean, it will autoscale at 0.5*(100) cpu utilization.

Comment: @abhishek627 I updated the link. It has been a while since I have worked with kubernetes, I am afraid I cannot help you with your question, sorry.

Comment: @abhishek627 "Hi, If I have defined my resources.requests.cpu as 100m and targetCPUUtilizationPercentage as 50% in hpa. Does it mean, it will autoscale at 0.5*(100) cpu utilization." Yes.

Comment: Link to topic seems to be moved to [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/blob/main/content/en/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale.md#algorithm-details)

Answer (score 20):

This is average cpu utilisation of all the pods, so if you have given requested CPU as `200` in the resource `requests` and `targetCPUUtilizationPercentage` as `80%`, then at `160` value of threshold, it will scale out the pod. It will create a new repliace.

Comment: "...so if you have given CPU as 200...", is this referring to the resource `limits` or `requests` of the pod?

Comment: `requests`, not `limits`.

Answer (score 1):

As of `autoscaling/v2`, `targetCPUUtilizationPercentage` is. no longer supported. Instead you may use `metrics` array.
Here's an example that would replace `targetCPUUtilizationPercentage` to achieve the same impact:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: my-deployment-hpa
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: my-deployment
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 10
  # Define metrics array for CPU utilization
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
    target:
      type: Utilization
      averageUtilization: 50
```

In addition to CPU, there are a number of other metrics that you can use to scale a HorizontalPodAutoscaler in Kubernetes. More on that here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/

Comment: The part `target` as well as its fields `type` and `averageUtilization` should be indented once so that it is in line with the `name` spec. See also the [Kubernetes docs here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#support-for-resource-metrics)